# Why are these issues arising with my swift code?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement a login through Parse, however, I am having a number of problems.

1. The first two If statements work but then perform a segue back to the first screen, even though there is no segue on my storyboard that even does this. So why is the alert popping up doing this? It doesn't wait or let me press OK.
2. When I sign up a user, it registers them (given the condition is met) to Parse but doesn't perform the segue which I have implemented? Fyi it doesn't show the alert error either.
3. On parse, there are frequently users signed up with random letters. I don't know how or why this happens.

Thank you in advance.

Jake

```
 if passwordField.text == "" || confirmPasswordField.text == "" || usernameField == "" || lastNameField.text == "" || firstNameField.text == "" {


            doAlert(title: "Incomplete Form", message: "You have not filled in all the forms")


        } else if passwordField.text != confirmPasswordField.text {


            doAlert(title: "Password mismatch", message: "Your passwords do not match")



        } else {

            let user = PFUser()
            user.username = usernameField.text
            user.password = passwordField.text
            user["First Name"] = firstNameField.text
            user["Last Name"] = lastNameField.text


            user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

                if error != nil {

                    var displayMessage = "Please try again later"

                    if let errorMessage = error?.userInfo["error"] as? String {

                        displayMessage = errorMessage


                    } } else {

                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "RegisteredViewController", sender: self)
                }
            })



        }
```

Comment: in your condition `usernameField` should be `usernameField.text`

Comment: do you have breakpoints in your xcode? try to go step by step and you will see what is wrong easily

Comment: don't forget to perform all UI updates on the main queue, like in the block of the signUpInBackground function

Comment: @lzl Please could you explain this to me? I am new to swift and coding in general so not sure what this means. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Basically I was user["First Name"]  wasn't working since Parse doesn't allow for spaces. In my doAlert I used this line, self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) as I thought that would dismiss the Alert but it actually dismissed the viewController, causing all kinds of problems. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: All the UI updates has to be done on the main queue, otherwise unexpected errors or crash might happen. For example I notice you have a signUpInBackground, I'm assuming it runs on a background queue, then you must call the performSegue on the main queue. Wrap it inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{ //UI updates })